# 3D Pie Chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d, pie-chart

I'm using d3.js to create Pie Chart.I have already developed the 2D chart and I need to do some changes in it which I'm not sure how it can be done.

This is chart I have achieved till now in 2D

[Fiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/qkHK6/2982/)

Now I'm trying to convert the same to 3D by following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181) example, but I'm not able to acheive this and I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.
Fiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/qkHK6/2984/

PS: I'm using d3.js version4.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I really appreciate if someone could help me achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fiddle doesn't work because it (1) uses D3 v3.x as resource and (2) the dimension of the SVG are too limited.

Change D3 to version 4.x and increase the values of 'h' and 'w' for the chart to render.

```
var w = 600;
var h = 400;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/2987/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply..I have updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/qkHK6/2995/. I still have problem with this. The bottom part is not in circular shape as it is supposed to be for a pie chart.How can I achieve that

Comment: Change the 'h' in the function call in line 36 to:


`.attr("d", function (d) { return pieOuter(d, rx - .5, ry - .5, h-200);`